# Function inside class not executed

Tags: python, django, database, function, class

I've a method inside a class with (CreateView) that i need to be executed, but i think it's not being executed, in fact 'save' do nothing and the table 'Card_id_user' is empty... Is there a way to solve this problem? Here is the code in my `views.py`

```py
class New_card_creation_view(CreateView):
    title = "AGGIUNGI CARD"
    model = Card
    template_name = "new_card.html"
    fields = ['card_title', 'description', 'expiration_date', 'column']

    def create_card_view(self, request):
        v = New_card_creation_view(request)
        v.create_card_view(request)
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = CardCreationForm(request.POST or None)
            if form.is_valid:
                form = form.save(commit=False)
                form.save()
                nCard=Card_id_user(user_id=request.user.id, card_id= form.id)
                return render(request, 'board.html'),
            else:
                form = CardCreationForm()
                return render(request, 'new_card.html', {'form': form})
        else:
            form = CardCreationForm()
            return render(request, 'new_card.html', {'form': form})

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(New_card_creation_view, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update({'title': self.title})
        return context

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('board_view', args=(self.object.column.board.id,))
```

Comment: why do you expect the `create_card_view` to be executed?

Comment: Because 'Card' has been create corectly and stored in its table. I thought i have to call `create_card_view`, but i need parameter `request` so i don't know what to do to retrieve parameter `request`

Comment: no that is just the boilerplate code of a `CreateView`. It automatically makes a form, etc.

Comment: it is however not entirely clear to me *what* you want to change to the `CreateView`, what "logic" do you want to add?

Comment: I have to add to the table Card_id_user the id of the Card just created and the user that created has that card

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [**`CreateView`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.CreateView) is basically just a simple class-based [**`View`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View) with some (a lot) of boilerplate code. It thus aims to simplify the work for the programmer. By adding a method like `create_card_view`, *nothing* changes, since this is not part of the code flow. Depending on the request, it will trigger the `.get(…)`, `.post(…)` method, etc.

Adding extra methods will thus not change anything. Only overriding existing ones and thus changing the code flow will.

If you need to do something after the form has been saved, you can make use of the [**`.form_valid(…)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.form_valid):

```
class New_card_creation_view(CreateView):
    title = "AGGIUNGI CARD"
    model = Card
    template_name = "new_card.html"
    fields = ['card_title', 'description', 'expiration_date', 'column']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        response = super().form_valid(form)
        Card_id_user(user_id=self.request.user.pk, card_id=self.object.pk)
        return response

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        return super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs, title=self.title)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('board_view', args=(self.object.column.board.id,))
```

Comment: I wasn't aware i could modify django's methods. Thank you, i'll keep in mind next time